# Unlink selection in the UV editor doesn't seem to work in 2.72

Tags: uv

I can't seem to get the "unlink selection" functionality in the UV editor to work inside Blender 2.72.

Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> does nothing. I have tried with the "keep selection in sync" -button both on and off. According to the Blender 2.6 manual <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> should unlink the selected islands. Has this been changed in Blender 2.72?

Comment: if you could post a `.blend` with an example of the `UV's` you are trying to unlink that you be great.